# MQ Queue MQTT_DEPT trying to generate multiple trigger messages

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

We have an HA application which runs on a few servers pointing to the same queue manager. Because the message sequencing is important we use a semaphore queue to make sure not two apps are reading messages from a business queue even if there are multiple messages waiting to be processed on that queue.

The work flow is something like below:

1. The business queue has a MQTT_DEPT trigger set on it to fire up when the queue dept is equals to one
2. The business queue receives one or multiple massages.
3. The trigger fires up when the queue dept becomes one and put a trigger message into an initiation queue.
4. Being a queue dept trigger it should switch itself OFF after delivering the trigger message into the initiation queue
5. There is a MDB listening to that initiation queue which gets the trigger messaage
6. Because sequence is crucial for us we put a limit on the initiation queue to have the maximum queue dept of one. This way only one MDB can get a message at a time
7. When the trigger message arrives the MDB goes and reads all messages from the business queue and when done it sends a trigger activate message to a dedicated queue.
8. Once this is done it commits everything. The trigger generated message gets discarded. At this point the trigger activation message becomes available for processing.
9. A trigger activating MDB gets the activation message and go and switches the queue dept trigger back on on the business queue so the whole process can kick off again.

In most of the cases all works fine. However now and then we get some messages in the dead letter queue which causes support calls by our monitoring tools. Inspecting the messages in the DLQ we noticed they are trigger generated messages and the reason for being sent to the DLQ is that the initiation queue was full (remember our limit of maximum one message).

We had no explanation about how this is possible. The IBM documentation says the triggering is switched off after sending the first trigger generated message but however from what we are experimenting it looks like wile the first trigger generated message gets processed and such is in an uncommitted state a second trigger generated message gets created and sent to the initiation queue. Not being able to deliver it (because of the max dept = 1 limit) it sends it to the dead letter queue.

Any inputs about why this would be possible and how to get around it would be very welcome. False support calls at 2:00AM are for sure not funny.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation for our problem was on the IBM MQ triggering documentation which we should read more carefully [IBM note](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026930_.htm):

Note: If you stop and restart the queue manager, the TriggerInterval timer is reset. There is a small window during which it is possible to produce two trigger messages. The window exists when the trigger attribute of the queue is set to enabled at the same time as a message arrives and the queue was not previously empty (MQTT_FIRST) or had TriggerDepth or more messages (MQTT_DEPTH).

Once we had the explanation the solution was simple. Rather than configuring the business queue to send the trigger generated message straight to the initiation queue we configured it to send to a different queue whit ho maximum queue dept restriction set on it. Then we implemented another MDB to get these trigger generated messages and redirect them to the initiation queue. This MDB was implemented two swallow any exception caused by an unable to deliver trigger generated message to the initiation queue because the existing queue dept limitation.

In other words with this new MDB we took the role of delivering the trigger generated message from the MQ manager in our hands and made the process ignore any delivery failure caused by the queue dept.